# Rails - regex needed with variable pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Take the following sample 2 data string and pattern.

```
value: webiste_landing_page_string?prs=kdfjg_sdfkrgfdkj=klfdjgldf;£lkjfsd£
value: webiste_landing_page_string?prs=klfdjgldf;£lkjfsd_io43"fdlkj;dfgfgg

pattern: prs=16
```

I need to return x chars after 'prs=' from the value strings, I will also be giving a pattern like 'prs=16' which tells me to return 16 chars after 'prs=' from the string.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the context? Are you having to parse a list of strings? Is this inside a controller and is this the visited url? E.g. can you access `params[:prs]`

Comment: it's actually a column in a csv and i need to extract the string based on the pattern. The csv i have parsed into a string.